# (Auto)-indent after the = in Pycharm/Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am relatively new to Python/Pycharm coming from a Matlab background. I noticed one thing that I am unable to reproduce in Pycharm/Python.

When I write code as follows:

```
albert = 1
b      = 2
```

And copy/paste it to a new file, I get:

```
albert = 1
b = 2
```

The alignment `=` disappears and everything gets cluttered to my opinion. As I am used to the alignment, I am having a hard time getting a quick overview of the variables and their values, in particular when the variable names are long.

How can I prevent this and also remove the warning? Why is it like this in the first place, I find it gets easily messy if you do not align your = for multiple statements?

In addition I was wondering if there is an auto-indent command like in Matlab (ctrl+R) to indent all the code properly.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with *PyCharm 2018.3.2 (Professional Edition)*. Copy/paste doesn't remove spaces for me.

Comment: And to remove the warning you would have to turn off PEP 8 inspection in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one of the following:

- On the main menu, choose `Edit | Paste Simple.`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+V</kbd>.

This way, it will paste it without any additional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, multilines alignments are mostly used to point out split lines. For example :

```
print('my first sentence',
      'my second sentence')
```

This is, I guess, one of the reasons it is not recommended to do it the Matlab way. Also, as far as I know, it is fairly more common to do it this way than the matlab way.

As for Pycharm, I'm not sure you can make it force this kind of coding style, but you could start by deactivate the "Assignment operators" rules in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python -> Spaces.

The warning is easy to deactivate : in Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> PEP 8 coding style violation, you need to ignore error E225.

Answer (score 0):

Python developers have some rule, even if it is not explicitly written. Without these rules, it would be complicated to read a code which is not from you.
One of the rule is that when you declare your variable b, there is a space before the '=' and after the '=', and pycharm is doing that for you.
You can find a style guide that explain all of the rules : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thats great, but I do not agree with that logic. Thus I would like my own and I do not care if someone else can read it.